# Sort array by other array sort indexing in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm having a bit of a difficulty. I'm trying to vectorize some code in python in order to make it faster. I have an array which I sort (`A`) and get the index list (`Ind`). I have another array (`B`) which I would like to sort by the index list, without using loops which I think bottlenecks the computation.

```
A = array([[2, 1, 9],
           [1, 1, 5],
           [7, 4, 1]])
Ind = np.argsort(A)
```

This is the result of Ind:

```
Ind = array([[1, 0, 2],
             [0, 1, 2],
             [2, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

B is the array i would like to sort by Ind:

```
B = array([[ 6,  3,  9],
           [ 1,  5,  3],
           [ 2,  7, 13]])
```

I would like to use `Ind` to rearrange my elements in `B` as such (`B` rows sorted by `A` rows indexes):

```
B = array([[ 3,  6,  9],
           [ 1,  5,  3],
           [13,  7,  2]])
```

Any Ideas? I would be glad to get any good suggestion. I want to mention I am using millions of values, I mean arrays of 30000*5000.

Cheers,
Robert

Comment: you are creating `Ind` and then immediately overwriting it on the next line, just FYI.

Comment: i just wanted to show the result of Ind .

Comment: I don't know... use comments or smth; it's confusing when you're obviously overwriting something you just created;  also while we're at it, check out https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ — you might find it useful in the long term.

Comment: I would have overwritten it with the same values as the results...im not here to pick a fight im here to solve a problem...i appretiate the comments and thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

A = array([[2, 1, 9],
           [1, 1, 5],
           [7, 4, 1]])
Ind = np.argsort(A)

B = array([[ 3,  6,  9],
           [ 1,  5,  3],
           [13,  7,  2]])

# an array of the same shape as A and B with row numbers for each element
rownums = np.tile(np.arange(3), (3, 1)).T

new_B = np.take(B, rownums * 3 + Ind)
print(new_B)
# [[ 6  3  9]
#  [ 1  5  3]
#  [ 2  7 13]]
```

You can replace the magic number `3` with the array shape.

Comment: You can use broadcasting instead of `np.tile` in order to get the row indices: `rownums = np.arange(3); B[rownums[:, None], Ind]`

Comment: Good point, it'll be useful if the arrays are huge. And your way of indexing looks clearer than mine.